# Store input value into session storage when form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, session, input, session-cookies

I have a form input

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="ip" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
        Name
    </label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input required type="text" value="{{ old('name') }}" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Cluster Name ">
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

I tried to set/store that name into my browser session.

> sessionStorage.setItem("clusterName", $('#name').val().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-"));

As soon as the form was submitted, I see nothing as the value of my `clusterName`.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow when I wrap it around

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("clusterName", 
    $('#name').val().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-"));
});
```

It is stored correctly now.